# How To Limit a WCF Service Application, So That Only Unique Clients Can Access

Tags: c#, wcf, service, limit, ip

i have a wcf service in c# (like the calculatorservice from msdn examples), and i was wondering is it possilble to limit it to serve only 1 client per IP?

i want the possibility of a few IPs to be connected at once (at least 5-6 active sessions), and that works for now, but i don't want more than 1 connection per unique IP (or unique computer)

Comment: Unless your service is for an intranet the IP address is not a unique per computer.

Comment: i know, what i want is only that is someone is already connected to the service, that he can't connect again through the same ip

Comment: maybe the better way to say it: while someone's session is still active, then he or she cannon get a new session until the first one is closed. and, yes, my service will mostly be used on intranet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i made some progress. when the client invokes the service for the first time, in the constructor i save his ip address and his current operation context.

then, if someone from the same ip connects, i abort the previous channel that that ip address used (newest connection has the priority):

```
operationContext.Channel.Abort();
```

i tested it, and it appears to free up the session so others can use it, but i am not sure -- is this the best solution?

Comment: this appears to be working satisfactory for now, please comment if you have any suggestions. i kept googling for a similar solution, but couldn't find anything useful.

Answer (score 0):

If you need 5 opened sessions at one time and you are saying that maxConcurrentInstances causes only 1 usuable client, have you set the InstanceContextMode to = PerSession? You most likely have it set to Single, in that case maxConcurrentCalls has no effect. Change it to PerSession and the throttling config ForeverDebugging has shown will work.

Comment: everything is pretty much on default setting, instancecontextmode is persession... and if i set maxConcurrentInstances="1" i only get 1 usable session, and if i leave maxConcurrentInstances to default, i can use around 10 sessions i think (which is enough for now).